# How to fix 'The selected XML schema contains more than one root node' prompt in Excel

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to import an XML schema into MS Excel 2016 based on some vendor documentation. When I do, it tells me there are multiple roots and wants me to pick one. I tried picking the first item, but it doesn't seem to import correctly or allow me to begin making the XML file. Can someone assist with where the problem is in this schema?

This is the first time I've tried this and my experience with XML is very limited. I have an inkling of an idea where the problem might be, but I'm not comfortable changing it without a more experienced eye on it first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema for OpenImport -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="MainSrcRefType" type="xs:short"/>
    <xs:element name="MainSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="NameSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="NameData">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="AddressSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="AddressData">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="CitySrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="CityData">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="CountrySrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="CountryData">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="BirthDateSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="BirthDateData">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="TINNumberSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="TINNumberData">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="BICSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="BICData">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="MatchList">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="MatchListEntry" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="MatchListEntry">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="MainSrcRefType"/>
            <xs:element ref="MainSrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="NameSrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="NameData"/>
            <xs:element ref="AddressSrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="AddressData"/>
            <xs:element ref="CitySrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="CityData"/>
            <xs:element ref="CountrySrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="CountryData"/>
            <xs:element ref="BirthDateSrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="BirthDateData"/>
            <xs:element ref="TINNumberSrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="TINNumberData"/>
            <xs:element ref="BICSrcRefID"/>
            <xs:element ref="BICData"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I expected it to import into excel and give me a table, headers, etc. so that I could input the needed data and export an XML file.

The example it shows for data file is:

The example XML file result shows:

```
<MatchList Name="FileName">
    <MatchListEntry>
       <MainSrcRefID>1234</MainSrcRefID>
       <NameData>John Doe</NameData>
       <-- SOME MORE FIELDS HERE REMOVED FOR BREVITY -->
    </MatchListEntry>
</MatchList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a single root element as a child of your `xs:schema` element. In your current configuration you have several "root" elements like

```
<xs:element name="MainSrcRefType" type="xs:short"/>
    <xs:element name="MainSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="NameSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="NameData">
    <xs:simpleType>
    ... <!-- 4 root elements till here -->
    ...
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

what causes the error. But you want only one. To resolve this, surround your further XSD with a single root element like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema for OpenImport -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="rootElement">   <!-- root element  -->
    ... <!-- Here come the four "root" nodes from above -->
    <xs:element name="MainSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="NameSrcRefID" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="NameData">
    <xs:simpleType>
    ... <!-- Here comes the rest of the whole XML file -->
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This, of course, has to be in sync with the XML files you're trying to validate. So check if your XML files have **one** root element - and if so, use that (its name instead of the placeholder "rootElement").

This root node denotes the single root node of an XML-1.0 file.
I haven't much experience with Excel, but now you should be able to import the file seamlessly.